# All files are missing from a downloaded Pod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

So I have tried to create a cocoa pod myself (iOS Swift library).I have successfully uploaded the files and have named my tag as 0.02.

I passed all the pod lib lint and pod spect lint tests..

But now when I try to create a sample app and download the pod, I only get the object ".h" file while all other files are not missing.

Anyone knows how to remedy this?

Comment: Did you include your swift files in the `s.source_files` line of the pod spec?

Comment: @Paulw11 no.. I just put a random string literal.. What should I put in there? (searching the internet now)

Comment: Something like `s.source_files  = "Classes", "MyProject/**/*.{h,swift}"`

Comment: @Paulw11 THANKS! It works now! Woo~.. One more question, how come the files are not contained in folders like how I have in GitHub? All the files are scattered outside. (No Folder at all)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; Do you have your pod spec file above the "MyProject" folder or inside it?

Comment: @Paulw11 My folders are arranged like this "My Project" -> {podSpect, License, Source{Core, Extension, info, ect}}

Comment: The root of your pod, once installed, will be the folder that contains the podspec. It looks like you need to move it up one level

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have included your Swift files in the `s.source_files` line in your pod spec.

Something like

```
s.source_files = "Classes", "MyProject/**/*.{h,swift}"
```